# password change script not working ouput is something's wrong

Tags: php, mysql

password change script is not working the output always shows up as something's wrong

```
<html>
<body>
<center>
<form method="POST">
Enter New Password:<input type="password" name="password"/><br \>
Confirm Password:<input type="password" name="conpassword"/><br \>
<button name="submit" value="Change My Password"/>
<button type="clear"/>
</form>
</center>
</body>
</html>
<?php
@mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("sarath");
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['name']))
header("location:login.php");
$n=$_SESSION['name'];
$p=$_POST['password'];
$cp=$_POST['conpassword'];
if($p==$cp)
{
 $query="UPDATE student
         SET password='$p'
         WHERE username='$n';";
 $r=mysql_query($query);
     if($r)
         echo "password changed successfully";
}
else
    echo "please enter the same password";
}
else
echo "something wrong";
?>
```

Comment: Did you get any error code ? If you get please add to your question.

Comment: what happens when you click on the submit button?

Comment: `<button>` elements are not *void elements*, in that they are considered malformed if they are not properly closed with a closing `</button>`. That's first. You should also change your `<button>` to an input: `<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Change My Password"/>` which will then satisfy your `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` condition. Or add `type="submit"` to your button and see if that works for ya: `<button name="submit" type="submit">Change My Password</button>`

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. This has many dangerous [SQL injection vulnerabilities](http://bobby-tables.com/) since you didn’t [properly escape values](http://bobby-tables.com/php). This code allows *anyone* to get *anything* from your site. **DO NOT** write your own authentication system. Any [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with an [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication) built-in.

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not use the [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It’s so awful and dangerous that it was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices. Your user parameters are **not** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) and there are [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) that can be exploited.

Answer (score 0):

You did some mistake such as

1. You need to use {} for if(!isset($_SESSION['name'])).
2. In your query you wrote following query in which you used ;  before query is over. ; is always come at the end of php line.

   $query="UPDATE student SET password='$p' WHERE username='$n';";

Try this code :

```
<?php
    session_start();
    @mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("sarath");
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        if(!isset($_SESSION['name'])) 
       {
         header("location:login.php");
         $n=$_SESSION['name'];
         $p=$_POST['password'];
         $cp=$_POST['conpassword'];
         if($p==$cp)
         {
            $query="UPDATE student SET password='$p' WHERE username='$n'";
            $r=mysql_query($query);
            if($r)
                echo "password changed successfully";
         }
         else
              echo "please enter the same password";
       }
    }
    else 
    {
       echo "something wrong";
    }
?>
```

I hope you will get your solution.

Comment: What did you do? You need to offer an explanation.

Comment: in the first place the else block containing echo something wrong shouldn't be there because every time that else block gets executed and that if clause will never get executed and i just removed the else block

Answer (score 0):

This means your $_SESSION ('name') is not set. When you are redirecting to change password page then you have to set the session variable and call it in the change password page. You can also do a var_dump(( $_SESSION ('name')); to check if it is set or not.